# Overlapping Header with Rest of Page

Tags: php, html, css, overlapping

I've just started learning HTML and CSS, so I know the basics, but I'm now trying to edit a page that is already full of HTMl and CSS and a little hard to read fora beginner.

This is the webpage in question: http://www.lymemd.org/indexmm5.php

I'd like to move up the navigation bar and everything below it to overlap with the light green header box, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I believe it has something to do with the positioning property, but the code is so messy I can't quite figure it out.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I can paste whatever code is necessary, but I don't even know what to paste here!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you want the nav bar to go inside the green box that as the logo?

Comment: sorry but the question is not clear

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not attempt a solution or provide necessary information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: What information do I need to give to make my question more clear slash give the tools to fix it?

Comment: please check my answer. it works can be seen in image

Comment: I can send you the source code by email or tell you can tell me where to upload to maybe a website

Comment: Do you have anyway I can contact you privately?  I don't know how I can thank you for offering your help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the image because it is too much to write in text
[image]

note the div contains more html

Comment: @Eric as you can see i have edited the html and it has worked. please comment back

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's still not quite what I'm looking for.  That brings the entire NavBar into the green header area.  How would I have it only go half into the header area?

Asked another way, if you look at the webpage right now, how would I move the navbar up 10 pixels, but keep everything else the same?

Comment: @Eric do what I showed you above then edit the height of the h1 element

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  Don't worry about it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try this...Edit the css.

```
#navArea {
width: 1050px;
margin: 0px 0; <!-- changed margin to 0px on #navArea-->
}
```

This works in my browser. If you need more help or this does not work please comment back.

Comment: Good solution! If you want to have a whole green page, replace the body {background-image: url(images/stripebg.png);} with: body {background: #e7f7ab;}

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick response.  For me, that just brings the nav-area right up to the green header box.  I want the nav area to actual be on top of the green header box.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I will look at the source again

Comment: @Eric hello looking at the source the navigation code is in the wrong place try moving it

Comment: @Eric I have found the answer

Comment: Not sure where I should move it to?

Comment: @Eric is the image not clear. I could send the source to you by email